# Define Function in Class

Tags: python, function, class

This may have an obvious answer, but I am trying to define a function within a class in python so that I can call the function similarly to how you call any variable from a class using namespaces. Is there a method to do so?

```
class Table():

    def __init__(self):

        self.table = [
        #    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
            [0, 5, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3], #1
            [0, 4, 6, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 1], #2
            [2, 0, 3, 0, 7, 0, 9, 0, 0], #3
            [0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], #4
            [0, 0, 0, 8, 3, 7, 0, 0, 0], #5
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0], #6
            [0, 0, 9, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0, 4], #7
            [4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 3, 7, 0], #8
            [5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 6, 0], #9
        ]

        def get(self, x=1, y=1):
            return self.table[y-1][x-1]

        def print_t():
            None
```

I would like to be able to call the "get" and "print_T" functions by using "Table().get" and "Table().print_T".

Comment: Try `Table().get()`

Comment: `get` has to access `self.table`, since `table` is neither a function-local name nor a global name.

Comment: The indentation is still broken. Are you *intending* to define `get` and `print_t` inside `__init__`, rather than `Table`?

Answer (score 0):

`Table().get()` will call your get function, as you need to initialize Table() first. You will need to add `(self)` to `print_t` for that function to work with the same call though!

```
Table.get()
>>>TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
Table().get()
0

Table.print_t()
#None
Table().print_t()
>>>TypeError: print_t() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class Table():

def __init__(self):

    self.table = [
    #    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
        [0, 5, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3], #1
        [0, 4, 6, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 1], #2
        [2, 0, 3, 0, 7, 0, 9, 0, 0], #3
        [0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], #4
        [0, 0, 0, 8, 3, 7, 0, 0, 0], #5
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0], #6
        [0, 0, 9, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0, 4], #7
        [4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 3, 7, 0], #8
        [5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 6, 0], #9
    ]

    def get(self, x=1, y=1):
        return self.table[y-1][x-1]

    def print_t(self):
        None
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Table().get()
    Table().print_t()
```

Like this will work.

Comment: `Table.get()` raises an `TypeError` as it expects a variable to be passed as self. This is due to Table not being initialized, so self not being set. This will not work.